# Open .docx file from Azure Blob

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm displaying a list of files within my page, I want to show the file in the browser when its `FileName` is clicked. The files are going to be always documents(`pdf`, `txt`, `.docx`). Everything is working fine except when the file has a `.docx` extension, when a file has a `.docx` extension the browser is trying to open it using `WinRar`. That is using Internet Explorer as the browser, when I'm using Google Chrome and try to open a `.docx` file then a tab in the browser is opened but there is any kind of symbols like : `PK!ß¤ÒlZ [Content_Types].xml ¢( ´”ËnÂ0E÷•ú‘·Ubè¢ª*‹>–-Ré{Vý’Ç¼þ¾QU‘ l"%3÷Þ3VÆƒÑÚšl    µw%ë=–“^i7+Ù×ä-d&á”0ÞAÉ6€l4¼½L60#µÃ’ÍS Oœ£œƒXøŽ*•V$z3„ü3à÷½Þ—Þ%p)Oµ^ “²×5}nH"dÙsÓXg•L„`´‰ê|éÔŸ”|—PrÛƒsðŽ?˜
`and the same thing happens when I try to open a`.pdf`using`Google Chrome.
This is my action, I just want to open documents in the browser when it's name is clicked, they are stored in Azure Blob...

```
  public ActionResult OpenFile(string fileName, int noteId)
            {
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName) + fileName);
container.GetBlobReference(String.Format("{0}/{1}", noteId, Path.GetFileName(fileName))).DownloadToStream(Response.OutputStream);
     return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Comment: you need a `Content-Type` header. Content-disposition has nothing to do with that. And note that a .docx is just a zip file. anything that does mime-type determinate based on file headers/magic numbers will say "zip".

Comment: @MarcB Great, adding Context-Type is asking now which program I will use to open it, then I choose `MS Office` and it opens... but it opens it separately as a `MS Office` file and not within the browser, I would like to open the documents in a new tab inside the browser :)